# Is there a way to create an index as real time and disk index in the same time?

Tags: sphinx

Is there a way to create an index as real time and disk index, in the same time ?
so I can wether index manualy or while inserting or updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this. A possible workaround is to implement a simple script which would populate your RT index using INSERTs and run it when needed (when you would like to run 'indexer').

Comment: thnks, actualy that was my last solution

Answer (score 2):

Well you run `ATTACH INDEX` command which converts a disk index to a RT index.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-attach-index

... in this way can 'bulk' create the a disk index first using `indexer`, attach to a RT index, and then continue to update it 'in real time'.

(of course kinda requires that the disk index and the RT index has the same settings/fields/attributes etc)